# Why won't html5 drag n' drop work on my ipad or android tablets?

Tags: android, html, ipad

I am currently using Adobe Flash (ActionScript 3.0) to provide my website visitors with drag and drop functionality.  This requires the Adobe Flash plugin which is not available to ipad users.  To make my site more accessible, I want to use html5 to provide drag n' drop functionality.  I cannot get the html5 drag n' drop code to work with my ipad or android phone.

It does work correctly with browsers I have tested on MacBook, Linux and Windows.

How can I offer drag n' drop to my users on Apple ipad and Android phone using html5?

Thank you.

EDIT:  Here is an example code that does not work on ipad and android but works on MacBook, Linux, Win:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop  :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1 {width:350px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
   ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Drag the W3Schools image into the rectangle:</p>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will have to supply some code, for us to be able to help you with your current situation

Comment: where is the code !!